# Call overloaded base class' function inside static function?

Tags: c#, inheritance, static

```
public class A 
{
    public int F () 
    { 
    // do something
    }
}

public class B : A
{    
    public static B F ()
    {
        B b = new B ();
        // do something more with b
        b.base.F (); // this doesn't work
        b.A.F (); // this doesn't work either
        return b;
    }
}
```

What is the proper syntax for calling A.F()? Please regard that B.F() is a static function.

Edit regarding the "change the name comments":

Please don't make the mistake to conclude from this stripped down to the essential example. Actually the functions are meant to read XML, and the function signature is `ReadXML (XmlNode parent, int id)` across all affected classes.

Comment: Have you tried `((A)B).F()`? Though my preferred solution would be to rename one of the Fs. :)

Comment: Can't this be considered a bad use of overloading feature?

Comment: You cannot call by this way, you should try to create a constructor in class A and inside this constructor call the method F()

Comment: Doesn't this gives you compiler warnings for hiding methods?

Comment: jv42: it does. But if you're not set up to treat warnings as errors it lets you build it still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the following will work (tested now so a proper answer) to call the F method of the A class.

```
    public static B F()
    {
        B b = new B();
        // do something more with b
        ((A)b).F(); // this works
        return b;
    }
```

You might like to think about changing the names. I find it hard to believe that a descriptive method name would be the same for something that returns an int and something that returns a class B. Perhaps the latter should have a Create in there somewhere since it seems to be some sort of factory method?

Comment: ... without knowing the actual application. The example has been cut down as much as possible.

Comment: @karx11erx: Yeah, this is why I just say you should think about it rather than you definitely should. I had assumed it was cut down and there may be more than we can see. Otherwise I'd have been complaining about your awful variable and class names. ;-)

Comment: I was only replying to Anthony. Thanks for your answer, this is what I was looking for. Could have figured it myself, but I was so stuck in thinking C++ ...

Answer (score 0):

I think it is impossible to use any keyword which needs to work with instance/inheritance, like `base` or `this` in static methods. As calling `F()` in class `B` there is no instance of class `B` so you can't refer to any `base`.

As an option you can create object of class `A` in `B.F()` and call `F()` of class `A` like `a.F()`, or you need to make `F()` in `A` as `static` and call `A.F()` from `B.F()`.

Comment: `B b = new B ();` would disagree with your statement that there is no instance of class B. Additionally your options will completely change the code in question. creating an object of class A in B.F() will not help to do things to the created b class. And making F() in A static will prevent it from doing things with the instances which I assume the "do something" is doing.

Comment: @Chris Seems you get me wrong... you can create instance of classes, but you can't use any keyword which deals with instance like base and this...

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean... I guess its useful to explain why what he did didn't work but I still don't think this answers the question particularly.